# Scripting in Adobe - How to convert a field to another type

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

Specifically, what I am trying to do is to turn a combobox into a text field on blur and back to a combobox on focus.  This would be my workaround for centering combobox text.  I've tried:

```
this.getField("fieldName").type = text;
```

but that hasn't worked for me.  Am I missing something?  Couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.  I've seen add-ons that can change field types, so what is the javascript for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. [The field type is read-only](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_properties.htm%23TOC_type5bc-48&rhtocid=_6_1_8_31_1_47).

You'll need to use two separate overlapping fields that show and hide each other. The other option is to just use a text field and run a script to show a popup menu on mouseup which also runs when you tab in. Users can select from the popup or type into the field.

Comment: That popup menu solves my problem, perfectly.  Far better than combobox.